# Can you get requests origin full path with node + express

Tags: node.js, express, https, request

I'm using node with express for my server. Is it possible to read full origin URL path of requests coming in.

#### Example:

Client is making a GET request from a page *[www.client-domain.com/animals](http://www.client-domain.com/animals)*  to *[www.server-domain.com/dog](http://www.server-domain.com/dog)*

I want to log */animals* on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per its definition, the [origin](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7) does not contain the path. Are you looking for the [referrer](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.referer)? But this is not included in XMLHttpRequests and may also be suppressed in navigation requests.

Comment: I have tried it, but im once again getting www.client-domain.com/ and not www.client-domain.com/animals